# Removing gap in settings

Tags: settings

Recently I have updated my nexus5 to android to 5.0. Is there any way to remove excess space in settings (empty space between rows) to display more on screen. Reducing the font doesn't help. 
Same goes with some applications (like gmail)

Thanks,
Marin

Comment: *prays to the universe that a solution to this exists*. google's new "material design" philosophy is ugly in my opinion and the forced color themes and all this extra negative space every where is hurting my eyes! google, please let me choose my colors and make things tiny and close together.